# C++ link static library to dynamic

Tags: c++, windows

**What I'm Using:**

- Windows 10
- C++ 20
- Premake
- Visual Studio 2022 (As a compiler maybe clang but for the purpose of this MSVC)

**Question:**
How would I approach wanting to link one library (static) into my own library (dynamic) and then be able to only ship my dynamiclib (Im on windows so dll)?

**Detailed:**
Basicly what I'm trying todo is put a bunch of libraries (In my case spdlog and fmt) into one large dynamic lib so i can ship it more easily as it is supposed to be a framework for working with graphical interfaces and i don't want to copy every library i used from my old project when i'm trying to start a new one.

**What I Tried**
I tried to staticly link libraries into my dll but for some reason there a some linking errors i cannot resolve.

Comment: A static library is really nothing more than an archive of object files. Linking with a static library is like linking with the actual object files themselves. As such, the object files becomes part of the final application or DLL.

Comment: Your goal is not clear to me. You want to merge the object code from the static library into the dynamic library so that you can ship only the dynamic library to clients who can then link with it? Please update your question to include more information. Perhaps it would be best to show us the actual linking errors that you are getting.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying todo. I provide code as soon as i can. Thank You!